# Ctags - Find where a function is used in a project

Tags: ruby, vim, ctags

Is there any good way to find where is a function being called in our codebase ?

Comment: Adding to @FDinoff's suggestion, look at cscope_maps.vim [http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_maps.vim] plugin.

Answer (score 2):

There is a gem called Starscope (disclaimer: I am the author) which can list function calls in ruby code, among other things. It isn't perfect, since it can't handle crazy meta-programming, but it will find all the normal calls to a given function.

- gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/starscope
- github: https://github.com/eapache/starscope
- user guide: https://github.com/eapache/starscope/blob/master/doc/USER_GUIDE.md

edit: Luc's answer is entirely accurate as far as it goes; I wrote Starscope specifically to be "Cscope for Ruby".

Answer (score 1):

With ctags, no. It references functions declarations and definitions, not their uses.
Then it depends on the language.

cscope can help with C, but not with C++. With C++, you should have a look at clang based solutions : there is [clang_indexer](https://github.com/LucHermitte/clang_indexer) (and its many forks) (see [vim-clang](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-clang) to integrate it in vim), but I did found a few quirks ; it seems YouCompleteMe does a few things related to code indexation (as it provides `GotoImplementation/Declaration` commands).

For other languages, you may have dedicated plugins. But for sure, there is always `grep` (and many plugins that integrates it)

Comment: thanks, I use ag to search the code base at the moment but it's not so efficient with large code base. And to be more specific, I'm looking for one to work with Ruby for now.